# Script for checking which button is clicked dosen't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have N(1..500) buttons create dynamically and I want know which button is clicked by the user and get the Id. I'm using this jQuery function but it doesn't work:

```
$(':button').click(function() {
    // reference clicked button via: $(this)
    var buttonElementId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(buttonElementId);
});
```

Comment: What does not work? event or you don't get id in event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are created dynamically you will need event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', ':button' , function() {
      // reference clicked button via: $(this)
      var buttonElementId = $(this).attr('id');
      alert(buttonElementId);
});
```

See [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements) for more info

Comment: Eh, I'm late for 9 seconds...

Comment: @Regent it's still valid +1

Comment: You know its duplicate then, Why did you not closed it?

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically created elements you should use:

```
$(document).on("click", ":button", function() {
    // reference clicked button via: $(this)
    var buttonElementId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(buttonElementId);
});
```